# How to profile React Native Expo app sluggishness on Android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am running into performance sluggishness on Android devices in a React Native tablet app on Expo ^47.0.13, using Hermes JS engine. The screen has a list and the "Add Item" feature to add an item to the list takes 4+ seconds to complete on Android tablets. I am able to reproduce the problem on a high-end, modern Android tablet ([Samsung Galaxy Tab S8 Ultra](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_tab_s8_ultra-11274.php)), so I know it's not a hardware issue. This sluggishness is happening on Android tablets only - on iPads everything works fine.

I'm aware that Expo 48 is available, but our app had stability issues on it with production builds so we are still on 47.

I’d like to use a profiling solution on a real device where I can reproduce the issue, see a timeline and pinpoint what functions are taking long to run on Android. However, I haven’t found any that work with Expo on Android:

Here’s what I’ve tried:

1. Expo’s built in [Chrome debugger](https://docs.expo.dev/debugging/tools/#debugging-with-chrome-devtools) - I can open the debugger but it doesn’t actually work with my app. I cannot see network requests and the profiling feature does not work: [image: Chrome DevTools Performance Monitor can't attach]
2. React DevTools - I would love to use the [profiling feature](https://reactnative.dev/docs/profiling) that’s built into React Native. However, none of the options lead to this from Expo. Per [Expo documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/debugging/tools/#debugging-with-react-devtools), I should be able to access the React Native profiling feature by pressing `Shift + M`. When I choose the "Toggle Performance Monitor" from the Expo menu, it says `✔ Dev tools (native only) › Toggle performance monitor` to show it’s on but nothing actually happens. Navigating directly to http://192.168.1.145:19000/_expo/react-devtools doesn’t work either, it says `Cannot GET /_expo/react-devtools`
3. Expo’s built in [Performance Monitor](https://docs.expo.dev/debugging/tools/#show-performance-monitor) - I am able to get this to show but it only has limited information. It doesn’t show me RAM usage (see screenshot), and it only shows me information about the page overall - I’d like to get information about the functions running over time so I can see what's slow:

[image: Performance Monitor]